# How to access span using beautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the number within the nested  tag. How would I do this?

My code outputs this, but I'd like to get the #40, not the whole two lines:

```
<span class="rankings-score">
<span>#40</span>
```

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

site =  "http://www.usnews.com/education/best-high-schools/national-rankings/page+2"

fields = ['national_rank','school','address','school_page','medal','ratio','size_desc','students','teachers'] 

r = requests.get(site)
html_source = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)

table = soup.find('table')    
rows_list = []      

for row in table.find_all('tr'):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    d = dict()

    d['national_rank'] = row.find("span", 'rankings-score')
    print d['national_rank']
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

when I try this:

```
d['national_rank'] = row.find("span", 'rankings-score').span.text
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

access the text of the nested span:

```
score_span = row.find("span", 'rankings-score')
if score_span is not None:
    print score_span.span.text
```

You need to make sure that `row.find("span", 'rankings-score')` actually found something; above I test that there *is* indeed a `<span>` found.

The `.find()` method returns `None` if no matching object was found, so in general, whenever you get a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ...` exception, involving an object you tried to load with `Element.find()`, then you need to test for `None` *before* trying to further access information.

This applies to `object.find`, `object.find_all`, `object[...]` tag attribute access, `object.<tagname>`, `object.select`, etc. etc.

Comment: Beat me to it... I was going to add that `class_='rankings-score'` or equivalent is probably wanted... Currently probably more a fluke that's the result...

Comment: So I've tried that before, but just said: row.find('span', 'rankings-score').find('span').text and get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

Comment: @goldisfine: some rows do *not* have such a `<span class="rankings-score">`.

Comment: so what's with the 'class_' as opposed to 'class'? Is 'class' a python protected word or something so BS uses class_

Comment: Exactly. `class` is a reserved word (used to define classes) so you cannot use it as a keyword argument.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by *any idea why restricted?*